# handling promises in parallel

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

i have a socket connection from my client service and receive an array of data.
based on each element in array i will create query and send to database.
how can i resolve this promises asynchronously?

```
Promise.all([p1, p2, p3, ...)
```

promise all is not useful for me because i need an event emitted after any of them is resolved.

each time any of this promises is resolved, i should do some job.

so i wondering if there is any way to receive an event per each promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply loop over the promise array and attach a `.then` handler to all of them, like this

```js
const promises = [p1, p2, p3, ...]
for (const promise of promises) {
    promise.then(() => console.log('done'));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The rxjs solution is to use `merge`

```
merge(from(p1),from(p2),from(p3))
.subscribe(()=>{.. will execute when any one of promise complete})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want:

1. Run then in parallel.
2. Do something when each promise finishes
3. Know when they are all done

You can do this:

```
Promise.all([
    p1.then(result => { /* do something when p1 is done; return result; */}),
    p2.then(result => { /* do something when p2 is done; return result; */}),
    p3.then(result => { /* do something when p3 is done; return result; */}),
]).then(allResults => {
    console.log("all promises done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

If you wanted to know when all of them were finished, even if some had an error:

```
Promise.allSettled([
    p1.then(result => { /* do something when p1 is done; return result; */}),
    p2.then(result => { /* do something when p2 is done; return result; */}),
    p3.then(result => { /* do something when p3 is done; return result; */}),
]).then(settledResults => {
    console.log("all promises done");
});
```

Now, usually, you wouldn't have `p1`, `p2` and `p3` in separate variables like this.  Usually, you would just make the function calls directly like this:

```
Promise.all([
    fn1(arg1).then(result => { /* do something when fn1 is done; return result; */}),
    fn2(arg2).then(result => { /* do something when fn2 is done; return result; */}),
    fn3(arg3).then(result => { /* do something when fn3 is done; return result; */}),
]).then(allResults => {
    console.log("all promises done");
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```